# Неважно, был клик по чекбоксу или по блоку, нужно сделать активным чекбокс и добавить класс блоку. При повторном клике убрать

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В этом коде все работает как надо только при клике на чекбокс. Нужно, чтобы аналогично работала смена класса у блока и активация чекбокса при клике на сам блок. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

```js
$('.cheaper-content__card').click(function() {
  $(this).find(":checkbox").attr("input-chek", "checked");
  $(".cheaper-content__card").toggleClass("selected");
  if ($(this).find(":checkbox").is(':checked')) {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cheaper-content__card">
  <div class="cheaper-content__chekbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="LV4010F0" name="LV4010F0" value="yes" class="input-chek">
    <label for="LV4010F0"></label>
  </div>
  <img src="img/cheaper-1.png" alt="">
  <a href="#">
  </a>
  <span> 9 690 ₽ </span>
</div>

<div class="cheaper-content__card">
  <div class="cheaper-content__chekbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="LV2010F0" name="LV2010F0" value="yes" class="input-chek">
    <label for="LV2010F0"></label>
  </div>
  <img src="img/cheaper-2.png" alt="">
  <a href="#">
  </a>
  <span> 4 990 ₽ </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Какой класс нужно добавлять/убирать при активном(или наоборот) чекбоксе?

Comment: `selected`? верно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).find(":checkbox").attr("input-chek", "checked"); // ?!` — `input-chek` — название класса. Атрибут «отмеченности» называется checked `.attr("checked", "checked")`

```js
$(".cheaper-content__card").on("click", function(e) {
  if ( $(e.target).is(":checkbox") ) {
    // Кликнули по чекбоксу, ничего не надо делать.
    return;
  }
  
  let $cb = $(this).find(":checkbox");
  $cb.prop("checked", !$cb.prop("checked")).trigger("change");
  //                   $cb.prop("checked") — true или false.
  // Устанавливается (!обратное) значение.
  // .trigger("change") — Вызывает событие "change", которое переключает класс. 
});

$(".cheaper-content__card").on("change", function(e) {
  // При любом изменении чекбокса...
  if ( $(e.target).is(":checkbox") ) $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.cheaper-content__card {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.cheaper-content__card.selected {
  border-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cheaper-content__card">
  <div class="cheaper-content__chekbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="LV4010F0" name="LV4010F0" value="yes" class="input-chek">
    <label for="LV4010F0"></label>
  </div>
  <img src="img/cheaper-1.png" alt="">
  <a href="#">
  </a>
  <span> 9 690 ₽ </span>
</div>

<div class="cheaper-content__card">
  <div class="cheaper-content__chekbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="LV2010F0" name="LV2010F0" value="yes" class="input-chek">
    <label for="LV2010F0"></label>
  </div>
  <img src="img/cheaper-2.png" alt="">
  <a href="#">
  </a>
  <span> 4 990 ₽ </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Все работает теперь как надо!
Там еще проблема была в css. Чекбокс стилизован через label, и у самого чекбокса стоял z-index: -1, что создавало проблему.
Стили чекбокса заменили на opacity: 0; z-index: 2; вынесли его таким образом поверх label и все заработало. Спасибо Вам еще раз за ответ!
Вы очень помогли!

Comment: Если ответ помог, его не худо бы отметить галочкой.